# Double clicks continously or refreshing the page in cakephp app log the user out everytime

Tags: cakephp-2.0, acl, logout

I am building an app for which I have used ACL component. It is a large project and difficult to post all the code here. SO I request others to please review this questions and answer why this happens. I have not specified any security level in core.php. But still the error persists.